# React: how to change page when using react-navigation and react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-navigation, expo

I am building a `react-native` application with Expo SDK 36.

This allows me to create an application for native environments such as iOS and Android, but with `react-native-web`, to also make it work on the Web.

Due to the fact that [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/) is not supporting browser history (window location change when navigating), I got recommended to only use the official expo routing library (react-navigation) with the native app, and use [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router) for the web.

Since I have two library in my project, I can use the `myRouter.web.js` that will export a router made with `react-router`, and `myRouter.js` that will export the navigation made with react-navigation.

This is how to use `react-navigation` to create a link between to pages:

```
<Button
  title="Go to Details"
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
/>
```

This is how to use `react-router` to create a link between to pages:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-web';

export default () => <Link to={'/details'}>Go to Details</Link>;
```

With these two syntax, how can I use the two to create links within my app, without using those two syntax everywhere in my source code?

I was thinking of creating a `Link.js` and `Link.web.js`, but not sure how I should implement it?

As an example, `Link.js`:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from 'react-navigation-hooks';

export default function Link({ to, screenName, children, ...rest }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Button
      title={children}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(screenName)}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}
```

And `Link.web.js`:

```js
import  React from 'react';
import { Link as RRLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Link({ to, screenName, children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <RRLink
      title={children}
      to={to}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </RRLink>
  );
}
```

This will force me to use `screenView` and `to` when creating `<Link />`. This because react-navigation does not have path, it just use a name.

Is there anything wrong I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

react-router also uses `this.props.history.push` to navigate to different screens. You might just be able to create a function that takes in the `history` or `navigation` and a variable for which it is like:

```
function move(hn, path) {
  !!hn.navigate ? hn.navigate(path) : hn.push(path);
}
```

And you could use it with: `move(this.props.history, '/somewhere')` and `move(this.props.navigation, '/somewhere')`.

Comment: That's not really how it work. We avoid creating source with such cross platform logic. Instead we prefer, `.web.js`, `.native.js` etc... I have updated my question with an example

Answer (score 0):

Using the two links below, this can be done:

`AppNavigator.js`:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { routes } from '../config';

const routeConfigMap = {};

routes.forEach(({ page, component }) => {
  routeConfigMap[page] = {
    screen: component,
  };
});

const stackConfig = {
  initialRouteName: routes.find(({ path }) => path === '/').page,
};

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(routeConfigMap, stackConfig);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

`AppNavigator.web.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { routes } from '../config';

function createSwitchNavigator(routes) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {routes.map((route) => (
        <Route
          key={route.page}
          path={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          component={component}
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  );
}

function createAppContainer(AppNavigator) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AppNavigator />
    </Router>
  );
}

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(routes);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

`config.js`:

```
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView';
import ListView from '../views/ListView';

export const routes = [
  {
    page: 'home',
    message: 'Home',
    path: '/',
    component: HomeView,
    exact: true,
  },
  {
    page: 'list',
    message: 'List',
    path: '/list',
    component: ListView,
    exact: true,
  },
];
```